# How to change an image from an ImageView inside a GridView?

Tags: android, audio, gridview

I'm currently creating my first "real" android application. It is a very simple sound box app with one activity.
For this sound box, I have a GridView which display items corresponding to a sound. This items are composed with a LinearLayout containing an ImageView and a TextView.
Basically what I want to do is changing the image of the ImageView on a click on the item associated with the ImageView, only during the time of the associated sound is playing.
With my code it will be better :

### activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#d6d6d6">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### list_row.xml :

There is only a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView.

### class Sound.java :

Contain only a constructor with two int, (one for the sound id and the other for the icon id) and one String for the description.

### class SoundAdaptater.java :

```
public class SoundAdaptateur extends ArrayAdapter<Sound>{

    private Sound[] items;
    private Context context = null;

    public SoundAdaptateur(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Sound[] items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SoundHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder = new SoundHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.description);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (SoundHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Sound sound = items[position];

        if(sound != null){
            holder.txtDescription.setText(sound.getDescription());
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.muscle1);
            //holder.imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.muscle1);
        }

        return row;
    }

    static class SoundHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtDescription;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Sound[] mSounds = null;
    private SoundAdaptateur mAdapter = null;
    private GridView mListView = null;
    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

        /*...*/

        mAdapter = new SoundAdaptateur(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_row, mSounds);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mp != null)
                    mp.reset();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, mSounds[position].getSoundResourceId());
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With this code, the app is working (the sounds are good) but the images never change.

#### Here is what I tried :

- I tried changing the image with the method `setImageResource()` inside the click listener but it didn't work
- I tried changing the ImageView with an ImageButton but after that the click listener event on the GridView wasn't working anymore. Even with the attributes `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:clickable="false"`.

  Do you have an idea of how I can resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should really be more focused and split your question into 2 different ones. I could read The Brothers Karamazov by the time I'll finish reading this one.

Comment: Ok now it should be better :)

Comment: Did you try something like this:
mListView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement onClickListener inside SoundAdapter , instead of onItemClickListener inside MainActivity.
in adapter, you can easily modify imageView.

but if you insist on implementing in MainActivity, you can iterate on children and find imageView and then change it's image. but it's not recommended:

```
for(int i=0;i<view.getChildCount;i++){
 View v = view.getChild(i);
 if(v instanceof ImageView)
  ((ImageView)v).DO WHAT YOU WANNA DO!
}
```

Comment: In fact it's working for changing the image source bur I can't my media player is not working if I start it in the click listener. Indeed, all the items on the screen will play the same sound.

Comment: @Mtoypc  first workaround is fine, you should create a separate class for holding and controlling media player object. for every item, position is different, just use this difference! second workaround is not the standard way.